# EA Trading bot with indicator

Tags: algorithmic-trading, indicator, mql5

I'm currently trying to build a trading Bot works with an indicator, I'm using the MQL5 language to build it .

I'm using the ichimoku indicator.

How to retrieve the value of every line of the indicator (base line, conversion line, the lagging line and the line A and B of the cloud) of a specific Bar on a timeframe for example:

```
(Timeframe H1
Bar : 2019/08/08 - 10:00 a.m
Symbol : EURUSD
▪︎base line : 1.1250
▪︎conversion line : 1.4050)
```

and so on for the other lines ...

I hope I made my question clear enough.

Comment: Have you read anything about MQL5? Check this link https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/indicators/iichimoku, for custom indicators use `iCustom` function

Comment: Yes I have, actually I analyzed all the lines of the code but I don't know how exactly to get values for every line for a specific Bar or candlestick. If you could make it more easier for me I'll be very thankful.

Comment: If you need to know values of some particular candle, you can use `iBarShift()`, or you can use `CopyBuffer()` with that time directly